# Find ID in HTML in JSON and insert in new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have this HTML in AJAX and I want to grab an ID (`#commentsContainer`) and insert in my other HTML.

Formatted HTML in AJAX:

```
<blockquote class=\"blockquote\" style=\"font-size: 15px; background-color: #f5f5f0;\" id='comments1'>
  <div id='commentsContainer'></div>
  </div><br>  
</blockquote>
```

The code I want to use and insert my new data

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/comments/",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      // console.log(data)
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var commentdesc = value.description;
        console.log(commentdesc)
        $('#commentsContainer').append("<li>" + commentdesc + "<li>")
        );
      })
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("error")
    },
  })
})
```

Comment: Typo: there's an extra `)` in the `each` block and an extra `</div>` in the HTML

Comment: you reduced your code too much. I cannot see any json. Please show the data you get, show what you want to select und then where you want to insert what at what place.

Comment: i want to insert in `<div id='commentsContainer'></div>`

Comment: That data is showing well in the console log

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes in your code.

Updated code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: "/api/comments/",
     method: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(key, value) {
         var commentdesc = value.description;
         $('#commentsContainer').append("<li>" + commentdesc + "<li>");
       });
     },
     error: function(data) {
       console.log("error")
     }
  });
});
```

**Mistake details:**

- Extra bracket next to `append` statement.
- Extra comma at the end of `error` method.

Hope this will help you after rectifying the mistakes.